Download CSV Using jQuery Ajax
How can I trigger a csv file download from the ajax jQuery method?
I don't want to use an href with the full url because I need to fetch the correct csv file depending on what id is selected in a dropdown.
Instead, I'd like to send a GET request which includes the report_id.
$.ajax({
    url: 'reports/generateCSV',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {report_id: id},
    success: function(data) {
        // what goes here to trigger download?
    {,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       console.error('Error fetching report: ', error);
    },
});

Here is the last bit of my Laravel controller method that streams the csv:
// ...
return response()->streamDownload(function() use ($data) {

     $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
     foreach($data as $row) {
         fputcsv($output, $row);
     }
     fclose($output);
}, $filename, $headers);


Inside the success bloc you need to parse your data that is inside the data variable. Like console.log(data);

You can create an <a> with a data href that includes your csv then auto-click it or you can simply change your $.ajax to an <a> with target=_blank so that the browser opens a new tab while generating the csv then closes it when the download has completed

Can't you use an <a> element whose href you build dynamically from the report_id? Or submit a <form> that contains the drop-down?
